# Compare two files for matching lines and store positive results

Tags: bash, files, file-comparison

I have two files.

#### File 1:

```
A0001  C001
B0003  C896
A0024  C234
.
B1542  C231
.
upto 28412 such lines
```

#### File 2:

```
A0001
A0024
B1542
.
.
and 12000 such lines.
```

I want to compare File 2 against File 1 and store the matching lines from File 1. I tried Perl and Bash but none seems to be working.

The latest thing I tried was something like this:

```
for (@q) # after storing contents of second file in an array
{
        $line =`cat File1 | grep $_`; #directly calling File 1 from bash
        print $line;
}
```

but it fails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print}' file2 file1
A0001   C001
A0024   C234
B1542   C231
```

Comment: @user3543389 - why did you pick this one over the grep solution? I'm just curious.

Comment: I have already tried that. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122636/match-first-columns-in-two-files

Comment: Although this one still doesnt give output with larger files

Comment: @user3543389: Do you mean "this one" is my answer? A note in your `perl` solution that you should use `while` loop instead of `for` loop.

Answer (score 27):

This should do the job:

```
grep -Ff File2 File1
```

The `-f File2` reads the patterns from `File2` and the `-F` treats the patterns as fixed strings (ie no regexes used).

Comment: Only downside with grep is that the awk solution is much faster for ~200 KB files.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like both files are already sorted on the first field.  If so:

```
join file1 file2
```

is best, by about as far as your files are large.

Comment: Tried this; each file must be sorted for this to work. In `grep` solution that is not needed.

Comment: @МатиТернер yes, this is true, keeping large files sorted saves much time (when they're big enough to pirate the R out of RAM 'cause L2's not even close to enough) and keeping small files sorted is too cheap to meter anyway.